# check box checked javascript

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to set a value in a text box based on whether the checkbox is checked or not
The function is attached to  onclick of the checkbox
This simple thing is not working :(

```
<div>
MyCheckbox
<input type="checkbox" id="Check1" name="FirstCkName" 
 onclick="testCheckbox(Check1,TextBx1)" />
 </div><br>

 <div>
  CheckBx Text Box
  <input id="TextBx1" name="CheckBxName"  type="text"  /> 
  </div><br>

<script>
function testCheckbox(oCheckbox,oTxtbox)
{

if (oCheckbox.checked == true)
{
    document.getElementById("oTxtbox").value=1;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("oTxtbox").value="";
}
}
</script>
```

Link to JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JS_learner/2750639m/30/

Answer (score 1):

Do something like.

```js
var checkBox = document.getElementById("Check1");
checkBox.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.getElementById("TextBx1").value = 1;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("TextBx1").value = "";
  }
});
```

```html
 <div>
  MyCheckbox
  <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" name="FirstCkName"  />
 </div><br>
 
 <div>
 CheckBx Text Box
  <input id="TextBx1" name="CheckBxName"  type="text"  /> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
onclick="testCheckbox(Check1,TextBx1)"
```

Here you're inventing your own parameters. That won't Work. The 'click' event is a predefined `Mousevent`, which will give an `'event'` argument.

The '`event.target`' will be the element you clicked.

This is how you should define this eventhandler:

```
onclick="testCheckbox"
```

Now you can write your script like this:

function testCheckbox(event)
{

if (event.target.checked == true)
{
    document.getElementById("oTxtbox").value=1;
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("oTxtbox").value="";
}
}